# STM32 interrupt from Matlab Code

Tags: stm32, c, embedded, interrupts

I'm using the STM32 MAT plugin and embedded coder for Simulink to generate C-Code out of my models to compile them onto an STM32F4. As IDE I use TrueStudio and for my MCU Configuration I use CubeMX.

Because my discrete solver step time in Simulink is set, it seems that the embedded coder tries to make a Software based Interrupt every 0.001 seconds.

```
 #include "main.h"
```

void SystemClock_Config(void);
 static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
 #include 
 #include "untitled.h"                  /* Model's header file */
 #include "rtwtypes.h"                  /* MathWorks types */

extern RT_MODEL_untitled *const untitled_M;
 extern void untitled_SetEventsForThisBaseStep(boolean_T*);
 static boolean_T OverrunFlags[1];
 static volatile uint32_t autoReloadTimerLoopVal_S = 1;
 static volatile uint32_t remainAutoReloadTimerLoopVal_S = 1;

int main(void)
 {
    int_T i;
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();

`/* Systick configuration and enable SysTickHandler interrupt */
if (SysTick_Config((uint32_t)(SystemCoreClock * 0.001))) {
   autoReloadTimerLoopVal_S = 1;
   do {
      autoReloadTimerLoopVal_S++;
   } while ((uint32_t)(SystemCoreClock * 0.001)/autoReloadTimerLoopVal_S >
         SysTick_LOAD_RELOAD_Msk);

   SysTick_Config((uint32_t)(SystemCoreClock * 0.001)/autoReloadTimerLoopVal_S);
   }

remainAutoReloadTimerLoopVal_S = autoReloadTimerLoopVal_S;//Set nb of loop to do

 for (i=0;i<1;i++) {
    OverrunFlags[i] = 0;
    } 
 untitled_initialize();

 while (1) {
    /*Process tasks every solver time*/
    if (remainAutoReloadTimerLoopVal_S == 0) {
     remainAutoReloadTimerLoopVal_S = autoReloadTimerLoopVal_S;

        /* Check base rate for overrun */
        if (OverrunFlags[0]) {
        rtmSetErrorStatus(untitled_M, "Overrun");
        }

        OverrunFlags[0] = true;

        /* Step the model for base rate */
         untitled_step();

        OverrunFlags[0] = false;
         } 
       }
 }


/* SysTick_Handler callback function*/
/*This handler is called every tick and schedules tasks*/

void HAL_SYSTICK_Callback(void)
{
/* For TIME OUT processing */
HAL_IncTick();
/* Manage nb of loop before interrupt has to be processed */
 if (remainAutoReloadTimerLoopVal_S) {
  remainAutoReloadTimerLoopVal_S--;
}
}`

Unfortunately when I try to run the Code, nothing happens. The Compiler always stucks at the if condition in the while (1) Loop. So I see that there's something wrong here with the Interrupt handling, but I don't know how to resolve the issue. Probably you can help

Comment: Without trying to be a smart aleck, it seems like you need to roll up your sleeves and learn how to use your tools.  As somebody who has done things like you're describing quite a few times, just getting up to the point you describe is a 20 to 40 hour process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable the interrupt in your NVIC.
Try adding:

```
NVIC_EnableIRQ(SysTick_IRQn);
```

before your while loop.

Comment: Hello there,

thanks for your answer. unfortunately that doens't make any difference :/
i have to admit that for the clock configuration, i use the pll with and external clock if that helps...

Comment: I did a Workaround by adding HAL_SYSTICK_Callback(); into the SysTick_Handler() function

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_SYSTICK_Callback();
}

Don't know if that's the correct way to do it...

Comment: Your startup file creates weak interrupts handlers. You can override this handlers and write your code in the new interrupt handler. What you did now is create a new irqHandler and called your callback function, this is fine.
Beware to not call HAL_IncTick twice.